# Python 3.9 difference list.sort(reverse=True) and list.reverse()

Tags: python, sorting

What is the difference? I don't see one in printout but for instance Hackerrank rated a result provided with "l.sort(reverse=True)" as wrong in an exercise while "l.reverse()" as right.

Here's my code (not optimized for easiness, I know):

```
#HR Lists

commands = "insert", "print", "remove", "append", "sort", "pop", "reverse", "rev"

#Anzahl Kommandos
N = int(input())
liste = []
command = []

for i in range (0, N):
    command.append(input().strip().split(" "))
    
    if command[i][0] == commands[0]:
        liste.insert(int(command[i][1]), int(command[i][2]))
    elif command[i][0] == commands[1]:
        print(liste)
    elif command[i][0] == commands[2]:
        liste.remove(int(command[i][1]))
    elif command[i][0] == commands[3]:
        liste.append(int(command[i][1]))
    elif command[i][0] == commands[4]:
        liste.sort()
    elif command[i][0] == commands[5]:
        liste.pop()
    elif command[i][0] == commands[6]:
        liste.reverse()
    elif command[i][0] == commands[7]:
        liste.sort(reverse=True)
    
print(liste)
print(command)
```

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: `l.reverse()` doesn't sort the list, `l.sort(reverse=True)` does. An unsorted list generally isn't the same as its sorted version

Comment: default sort is in ascending order. `reverse=True` will sort in descending order. `reverse()` will just reverse the current list, no sort whatsoever. They will be the same only if original list is sorted in ascending order.

Comment: `list.reverse()` just reverse the list and `list.sort(reverse=True)` sort in descending order

Comment: Thanks so much folks. Got it! Have a nice day!
Question answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 examples with an exact same list `l` and here are 2 different results :

```
l = ['a','c','b','d']
l.sort(reverse=True)
print(l)
```

result : `['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']`

`sort(reverse=True)` sorts the list in a reverse order ( `'a'` last, `'b'` before last and so on).

```
l = ['a','c','b','d']
l.reverse()
print(l)
```

result : `['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']`

`reverse()` just reverses the list without sorting (puts the last item first, the item before last becomes second ... and so on).

Answer (score 0):

`list.sort(...)`, as its name suggests, sorts the list. If the list is unsorted, `list.sort(reverse=True)` will sort it in reverse order. If the list is already sorted, it will sort it in reverse order (i.e. reverse it) - but will likely take longer than `list.reverse()`.

`list.reverse()` simply reverses the list, and is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of what you want to accomplish. If just reverse the order - then the reverse(). If also take values into attention - then sort().

```
l = [1, 5, 3]
print(l.reverse())
Out: [3, 5, 1]

print(l.sort(reverse=True))
Out: [5, 3, 1]
```